# Selenium Webdriver is failing due to page crash in AWS ECS container

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to run some selenium test code inside AWS ECS container.

I am passing the following arguments to ChromeOptions

```
options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200",
          "--ignore-certificate-errors","--no-sandbox","'--disable-dev-shm-usage");
```

The error I am getting the below error. Usually, it happens only when `"--no-sandbox","'--disable-dev-shm-usage"` flags are not added

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from tab crashed
```

Comment: Why are you deleting your old [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746232/selenium-webdriver-is-failing-due-to-page-crash-in-docker) and asking the same question again and again?

Comment: I made it more specific from docker to Amazon ECS. In docker, it got solved by passing `--disable-dev-shm-usage`. But in Amazon ECS I am still facing the issue.